# What is the song played by Lee Min Ho in Legend of the Blue Sea Episode 2?

Tags: identify-this-song, korean

Lee Min Ho plays a song with guitar in Legend of The Blue See Episode 2.
Here is the frame: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiNurV56gA4&lc

What is this song?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Janice Lim's comment the YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiNurV56gA4&lc=UggZZnt7l1RudngCoAEC.8Nikqu5jQ0K8O4xaoYt7Uq),

> 사랑은 언제나 오래 참고 （Love is Always Patient)

It's a Christian/gospel song (which supports the church scene in the video) based on [1 Corinthians 13:4-6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Corinthians+13%3A4-6&version=ISV).

> Love is always patient; love is always kind; love is never envious or arrogant with pride.
>
> Nor is she conceited, and she is never rude; she never thinks just of herself or ever gets annoyed.
>
> She never is resentful; is never glad with sin; she's always glad to side with truth, and pleased that truth will win.

Here's the [romanized lyric](http://lyrics.jetmute.com/viewlyrics.php?id=350988).

> sa-lang-eun eon-je-na o-lae-cham-go
> sa-lang-eun eon-je-na on-yu-ha-myeo
> sa-lang-eun si-gi-ha-ji an-eu-myeo
> ja-lang-do gyo-man-do a-ni-ha-myeo
>
> sa-lang-eun mu-lye-hi-haeng-chi an-go
> ja-gi-ui yu-ik-eul gu-chi-an-go
> sa-lang-eun seong-nae-ji a-ni-ha-myeo
> jin-li-wa ham-kke gi-ppeo-ha-ne
>
> sa-lang-eun mo-deun-geol gam-ssa-ju-go
> ba-la-go mit-go cham-a-nae-myeo
> sa-lang-eun yeong-won-to-lok byeon-ham-eob-ne
>
> mit-eum-gwa so-mang-gwa sa-lang-eun
> i-se-sang-kkeut-kka-ji yeong-won-ha-myeo
> mit-eum-gwa so-mang-gwa sa-lang-jung-e
> geu-jung-e je-il-eun sa-lang-i-la
> geu-jung-e je-il-eun sa-lang-i-la

One of the full renditions of the song on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A17YXyqt3os).